# React JS: Getting [object object] When Concatenating Object Element With String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, variables, concatenation

Im defining row content in React Table, when type the element variable alone it will print correctly, but when I try to concatenate it with other variable I get [Object Object] instead

the Object:

```
// Icons object
const typeIcons = {
  DINEIN:  <FlatwareIcon color="secondary" />  ,
  DELIVERY: <DeliveryDiningIcon color="secondary" />,
  TAKEAWAY: <RoomServiceIcon  color="success"/>
}
```

When using object element with type 'DINEIN' for example, it works perfectly :

```
row2: typeIcons[item.order_type],
```

and gives the required icon, But when concatenating with other variable, i.e.

```
row2: typeIcons[item.order_type] + item.order_type,
```

the outcome will be:  [Object Object]DINEIN
Any explanation ?
Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: What do you expect when attempting to concatenate a React component and the string? Should the string be rendered after the React component?

Answer (score 4):

`typeIcons[item.order_type]` is object(React component) while item.order_type is a string. You cannot concatenate string with object.
I assume value under `row2` must contain a React component, then you can try something like this:

```
row2: <>{typeIcons[item.order_type]} {item.order_type}</>,
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that works just fine.. I was missing the point where react Component object should not be treated as object member.

PS. I am not able to accept or upvote because of my account limitation, but upvoted anyhow.